# Get-ItemProperty with Registry, returned object type

Tags: powershell, types

I can use `Get-Item` with folders, files and registry keys, and the type of the object I get back will make sense; `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`, `[System.IO.FileInfo]` or `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]`.

But with registry properties, what using `Get-ItemProperty` returns is a `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`. Is this because there is no dedicated type for registry property? That seems odd. But my Google-Fu is not turning anything up.

My use case is this, I am doing a series of Copy and Move tasks, with all four item types potentially getting copied or moved, and I want to implement an option to rename an existing destination rather than overwriting or failing. And exactly what the rename options are depends on the object type. And from a readability standpoint, `PSCustom Object` or a simple `else` for RegistryProperty is a bit ugly. So, looking for a way to get the property back as a type with a more obvious name, so when I look at the code again in 12 months it makes some sense.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Just made a small correction to my answer: You _can_ base parameter declarations on ETS type names, namely via the `[PSTypeName()]` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) returns what is conceptually a registry *value object*: a property of a registry *key* that has a name and a - uh... - value (the named value object's *data*).

The .NET registry API has *no* type to represent such a value object - instead, it allows access via the registry *key* type's `.GetValue($valueName)` (to get a specific value object's data<sup>[1]</sup>) and `.GetValueNames()` methods (to get the list of all value names).

The PowerShell implementers apparently chose *not* to implement their own .NET type, and chose to use PowerShell's general-purpose, dynamic "property-bag" type, `[pscustomobject]`<sup>[2]</sup> to model these value objects.

If you want to avoid the `[pscustomobject]` instances that `Get-ItemProperty` returns, you can use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) instead, which returns a [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) instance, i.e. an instance of the .NET type representing a *key*, on which you can invoke the methods mentioned above.

As an aside: If you're just interested in a given value object's *data*, you can use the PSv5+
[`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) cmdlet (e.g.
`Get-ItemPropertyValue HKCU:\Console -Name LineWrap` directly returns the `[int]` data of the targeted value).

---

<sup>[1] Additionally, as [js2010's answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69968148/45375), the [`.GetValueKind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind) method returns an `enum` value that identifies a given value object's [*registry-specific data type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind). These types  *imply* what *.NET* types are used to represent them, as returned by `.GetValue()`, but in some cases *have no direct equivalent* (`ExpandString`, `MultiString`, `Unknown`) and require additional work to interpret them correctly.</sup>

<sup>[2] It is possible - but wasn't done in this case - to assign (one or more) *self-chosen type names* to `[pscustomobject]` instances, which PowerShell reflects as the type name in [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) output (only the first, if there are multiple) and which it respects for ETS type definitions and format-data definitions. However, such pseudo types are *not* accessible as *type literals*; e.g.: `$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ PSTypeName = 'MyType'; prop = 'foo' }` allows you test for this type name with `$obj.pstypenames -contains 'MyType'`, but *not* with `$obj -is [MyType]`. That said, you *can* base parameter declarations on them, via the [`[PSTypeName()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName) attribute.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the type of the properties:

```
$key = get-item hkcu:\key1


$key.GetValueKind('value1')

DWord
```

Comment: Note that what the [`.GetValueKind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind) method returns is _not_ a .NET type in itself but an `enum` value that identifies [_registry-specific data types_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind) that _imply_ what .NET types are used to represent them, but in some cases _have no direct equivalent_ (`ExpandString`, `MultiString`, `Unknown`).

Comment: I would also add that the "value kind" is a hint to the program reading the registry data as to how the "blob" of data should be interpreted, but it's really only a suggestion. (The Windows APIs don't care if you store a string as `REG_BINARY`, e.g.)